# preg_split : How to get what's before the split

Tags: php, string, preg-split

I'm having some issues with the preg-split function.
I would like to get what is before the delimiter instead of what's after it.
I've found some leads explaining that using the following code would do the trick :

```
$var = end(preg_split('/\./',$string));
echo($var[0]);
```

But when I'm doing that I only get the first char and not every chars before the dot.

Here is my code :

```
$item = "software_technical_item.TI";
$joint = end(preg_split('/\./',$item));
```

I obviously get "TI" in `$joint`, I would like to get "software_technical_item", would someone know how to do that ?

Thanks,
Corentin.

Comment: `.` as a regex means any individual character. Why not explode on `.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot is a special character in regex which matches any character , you need to escape it in-order to match a literal dot.

```
$string = "software_technical_item.TI";
$var = preg_split('/\./',$string);
echo($var[0]);
```

Output:

```
software_technical_item
```

Comment: Yes thanks @Avinash, I actually forgot to copy it but it's like you said in my code (edited). But I still get only "s" instead of "software_technical_item" :/